# How to make a split oil sauce

Tags: sauce

I am watching masterchef: the professionals

They have a few recipes about a split oil sauce

Google shows how to fix a split sauce. That is not my question

My research shows this is where they purposely combine a water based and oil based sauce

What would a basic recipe look like to achieve this split oil sauce?

Comment: Water & oil don't want to mix. They will naturally separate. The difficult part is to persuade them not to; to maintain an emulsion. Letting them separate requires no effort at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple Asian style dressing or dipping sauce would qualify as a split oil type sauce from that description, containing as basics Soy Sauce, Toasted Sesame Oil, Rice Vinegar and/or Mirin.

So would a simple Italian style bread dipping sauce, with Olive Oil and Balsamic Vinegar (and herbs, garlic, etc.)